# UISearchBarStyleMinimal shows scope buttons on top of UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uisearchbar

When I apply UISearchBarStyleMinimal my scope buttons get drawn over the search bar. Here is how it looks like on regular style:

[image]

And when I apply the style, I get something like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this happens, and what can I do to fix it. When I remove the scope buttons it look really nice, but I need the scope button for my app.

Comment: Did you find out what was going on with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ended up using the regular style.