# Swift - Scope buttons visible on top of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift

I created a search bar and a scope bar, but when the page launches the scope buttons are directly visible behind the search bar. I know that the .Minimal setting makes my search bar translucent, but it gives me a nice grey color that looks great on a white background.

Clicking on the search bar and then the cancel button will display everything correctly. The link below shows exactly what I am talking about.

[UISearchBarStyleMinimal shows scope buttons on top of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571683/uisearchbarstyleminimal-shows-scope-buttons-on-top-of-uisearchbar?rq=1)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**SearchController.swift**

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create search bar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "btn1", "btn2", "btn3"]

    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    UISearchBar.appearance().searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = Constants.MAIN_THEME_COLOR
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with my search but resolved it by adding this line:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
```

Comment: Where exactly did you add this line? Adding it makes my buttons visible right from the start :( they should only be visible when the user is in search mode.

Comment: If you add it to the ViewDidLoad then they will appear straight away.

I added mine like this:
`func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {`
        `self.searchBar!.showsScopeBar        = true`
        `self.searchBar!.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "btn1", "btn2"]`
}`

Comment: What if I want them visible again when search did end editing?